# Turning off chunk coloring in Emac's nXhtml mode

Tags: emacs, colors

```
(load "~/.elisp/nxhtml/autostart.el")
(setq mumamo-chunk-coloring 'no-chunks-colored)
```

I currently have the above in my .emacs and the chunk coloring is still showing up.  I have also tried disabling it through customize-option and then setting the state to "no chunk coloring" in mumamo-chunk-coloring.  I'm using the latest emacs23 from cvs and have the most recent nxhtml release.

What is the correct way to disable the coloring of different major modes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bug. I forgot to add this possibility back when implementing chunks in chunks.

I have just corrected this in 1.88 (which is yet in beta).

Note that in the new version you will use a number for mumamo-chunk-coloring. Set this to 1 to avoid coloring main mode chunks etc.

BTW: Just happened to see this. If you want bugs to be corrected it is normally much better to report them in nXhtml bug database on Launchpad.