# Emacs, Django templates and script blocks

Tags: javascript, django, emacs, ide

I use emacs when working with Django. .py files work great with Python-mode, .js files work great with js2-mode, .djhtml (templates) work great with django-html-mode -- *except* for Javascript blocks which aren't auto-indented nor highlighted.

Does anyone know of a way to get syntax-highlighting for Javascript blocks in Django templates in emacs?

Comment: Have you got MuMaMo? (Multiple Major Mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `django-nxhtml-mumamo-mode`. It is part of the [nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) package. (It is shipped with [Emacs Starter Kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit), too.) For JavaScript, it uses `javascript-mode` instead of `js2-mode`.

Comment: Works great. Do you know how to stop the dratted chunk-colouring that nxhtml does? Related discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146701/turning-off-chunk-coloring-in-emacs-nxhtml-mode

Comment: Right, figured that one out myself, the answer is here: http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html#multi-colors